# Java nio socket waiting time when a buffer is full

Tags: java, buffer, nio

I am using java nio socket for communication. When the speed of message publications is high, the write buffer is filled up and the process has to wait for the next writable time. The frequency of send buffer full is high. The unsent buffer is enqueued.  I measure the end2end delay of my experiments, it takes ~900 ms. At the same time, I measure the difference between the dequeu time of a unsent buffer and the enqueue time of the same buffer. I find it takes hundreds miliseconds.

Then, how to reduce the waiting time for the next writable time? Windows XP is installed on my machines and the project is Java code.

I hope people who have a lot of nio and system experiments can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The send buffer fills when the peer reader is slow reading. You can't do anything about that except speed up the peer reading process. Nothing you can do at the sending end.